# How to figure out if a request coming from facebook?

Tags: facebook, web-crawler, user-agent

We have a requirement of not sending a specific ajax request to our server if the page is requested by Facebook scraper (we share the link to our page on the facebook wall) and we try to check the user-agent in javascript based on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler/ but we noticed that we are getting quite many requests by facebook IP address with normal user-agents (like "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36")  is it a bug? Any workaround (except looking for facebook ip-addresses)?

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned User-Agent only comes into play when the Facebook scraper requests your URL - but the scraper doesn’t execute any JS to begin with, so trying to “suppress” any AJAX requests in *that* scenario doesn’t make sense to begin with - because there simply aren’t any.

> if the page is running by Facebook

Can you please clarify what you actually mean by that? “Running by Facebook” is not really phrasing that makes much sense.

So please explain in what exact scenario you need to suppress this AJAX request. Are you talking about a normal page visit in the Facebook in-app browser? Or a context where your content gets embedded *on* Facebook, like a Page Tab or Web Games app, or Instant Gaming, or …?

Comment: Thx, I updated my question, but are you sure about "Facebook scraper doesn’t execute javascript" ? any link to a resource?

Comment: I don’t know if Facebook themselves have documented this anywhere, but it is rather “common knowledge”. Look at any question here where people have problem swith their Angular app or SPA in general, where they are trying to set OG meta tags dynamically at run-time via client-side JavaScript - the answer is always going to be, that’s because the scraper doesn’t care for any JavaScript.

Comment: Facebook also has some pre-loading mechanism in their mobile apps, to fetch URLs linked to in the news feed in the background, before the user even clicks on them - but AFAIK they use a special User-Agent for that, and it would also not explain why these requests come from Facebook IPs, I think in that case you should rather see the IP of the user’s mobile device.